# Compilaton errors compiling a Cydia tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia

I am trying to make my first Cydia tweak with Objective-C so I followed [this guide](http://www.thinktank.news/how-to/tweak-development/popuponstart/). I get to the part where I am to compile my code with the command "make package install" and when I type this, I get a massive amount of errors. This is my code for the Tweak.xm file from the guide:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
%orig;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@”Hello World”
message:@”This is my first tweak and I’m happy!”
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@”Youhou!”
otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}

%end
```

I can't for the love of god figure out what is wrong. I have retyped my code about a 100 times, I even copy-pasted it from the guide to check if I was making any typos. I have Theos installed and in my Theos folder I have an "Include" folder where I have put the header files from the tutorial so it should work.

This is the full error code:

```
sh-3.2# make package install
Making all for tweak PopupOnStart...
Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Compiling Tweak.xm (armv7)...
In file included from Tweak.xm:1:
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:3:26: error: cannot find interface     declaration for 'UIApplication', superclass of
  'SpringBoard'; did you mean 'SBApplication'?
@interface SpringBoard : UIApplication
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     SBApplication
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:1:8: note: 'SBApplication' declared here
@class SBApplication;
       ^
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:3:26: error: attempting to use the forward     class 'SBApplication' as superclass of
  'SpringBoard'
@interface SpringBoard : UIApplication
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:1:8: note: forward declaration of class here
@class SBApplication;
   ^
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:12:31: error: unknown type name     'UIWindow'
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
                          ^
/Users/Admin/popuponstart/theos/include/SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h:12:1: error: property with 'retain (or     strong)' attribute must be of object type
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
^
Tweak.xm:6:1: error: unknown type name 'UIAlertView'
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World"
^
Tweak.xm:6:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIAlertView'
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World"
                   ^
6 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/Tweak.xm.3ff78cf9.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/PopupOnStart.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [PopupOnStart.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Basically the compiler is giving me an error about just about everything in the code, I just don't understand. I did everything exactly like in the tutorial. Can anyone please help, has anyone followed the guide?

Comment: I think it's the quotes. Those should be `"`s instead of `”`s. For reasons, some webpage tend to f-up code syntax. clang has pointed out almost everything you should correct in the error output.

Comment: Thanks, part of it was the quotes. But it still does not work, I am getting the following 6 errors:

Comment: Please update your question based on those changes.

Comment: I just updated it, thanks for replying. It is giving me 6 errors now all related to the different identifiers. I have no idea what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Does add `@import UIKit;` to the first line helps?

Comment: No it just gives me 7 errors instead, the new error being: "Tweak.xm:1:1: error: unexpected '@' in program
@import UIKit;"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106861/discussion-between-ofelia-van-analhard-and-zhi-wei-cai).

Comment: Change it to `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`?

Comment: Now its onlygiving the error: Making stage for tweak PopupOnStart...
dpkg-deb: building package 'com.yourcompany.popuponstart' in './com.yourcompany.popuponstart_0.0.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make install requires that you set THEOS_DEVICE_IP in your environment. It is also recommended that you have public-key authentication set up for root over SSH, or you will be entering your password a lot.
make: *** [internal-install] Error 1 How do I set theos device iP?